# changing table name stops the mysql query from returning row

Tags: php, mysql

i am returning mysql row from query . it works fine but when ever i chang the table name it stucks and returns nothing ,strange for me.
the second table is quite big with 28 feilds.
code goes here! ANY help Appreciated.
it works fine if i change table name to settings or other but when ever i change it to order it stucks.

```
function showorder(){ 
$query = "SELECT * FROM order";
if($resultset = $this->dbobj->runQuery($query)){
    if ($resultset->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $resultset->fetch_assoc(); 
        $carresult = $row;

        } else {
            $carresult = NULL;
            $carresult .= "sorry no settings founds";

        }
    } else {
        $carresult = die( $this->db->errno );
    }
    $resultset->close();

      return $carresult;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Order` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in mysql.

if you whant to use it as a table name you have to enclose it with backticks.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order`";
```